# How can I create a reproducible example for a dendrogram object?

Tags: r, dendrogram

I have an issue from a previous question which involves applying a function to a dendrogram object named `dend`, which produces an error.

```
function(x){
    if(attributes(x)$height<0){
        attributes(x)$height = 0.0001
    }
    x
}

dend = dendrapply(dend,positiveheights)
```

> Error: C stack usage  7969556 is too close to the limit

where:

```
> dend
'dendrogram' with 2 branches and 20000 members total, at height 12.0029
```

```
> summary(dend)
     Length Class      Mode
[1,] 2      dendrogram list
[2,] 2      dendrogram list
```

I need to provide a reproducible example of `dend` for the question, but it is much too large to `dput()`.

If I needed to create a reproducible example of a very large matrix, I could simply do `set.seed(123); matrix(rnorm(big_number))` which can easily be reproduced by anyone.

How can I do something similar for the `dend` object, whilst capturing the most important features of `dend` which might be relevant to the question (e.g. branch heights).

Comment: Adding to the answer provided below, I suggest looking at the set function in dendextend. It allows you to control many aspects of the dendrogram. This will allow you to adjust the dend to showcase the bug you have.

Answer (score 2):

You can produce an object of class dendrogram from a "dendrogrammable" object with [`as.dendrogram()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/dendrogram). Suitable objects are, i.e., outputs from [`hclust()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/hclust), for which you can use the example dataset `USArrests`. Thus:

```
hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave") |> as.dendrogram()
```

gives you an example dendrogram.